# How do I calculate probability confidence interval from a small sample?

Tags: probability, statistics, confidence-interval

I'm new to calculating probabilities, so I need my math checked on this.

I have taken a sample of 7 of a population of 2550 on a binomial test. First, I wanted to see if there are only 3 yeses in a 2550 population, what are the odds that I selected all three in a sample of 7. I used C(2550,7)/C(840,1).. or 1.38x10^20/840. I hope that is the correct math?

$n=2550$

$r=7$

$C(2550,7)/C(840,1) = 1.38(10)^{20}$

Given such a low probability, and not knowing the true number of yeses, I'm hoping to draw some high-threshold conclusions about my small sample of 7. If my sample shows 42.9% yeses, what is my 99% lower level confidence interval? z = 2.33. Mean of the bimodal is .4286, stdev is .5345. That gives me +/- 47.1%, or outside the bounds. Am I looking at this right?

$n_,=7$

$\mu=.4286$

$s_1=.5345$

$z=2.33$

Comment: Could you edit your question, using the following link to adjust all the math in it? Would be much more clear for people and the help will be bigger: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Gave it a shot; learning curve that I'm willing to work through, but not comfortable with it yet.

Comment: $\frac{\binom{2550}{7}}{\binom{840}{1}}$: do you mean to do this? And $1.38*10^{20}$ is very high, so I think you meant something else?

Comment: The first part of the question: If there are 3 Jokers in a pack of 2550 cards, and I draw 7 cards, what are the odds all 3 jokers are in the 7 cards I drew? (assuming a random distribution of the jokers in the deck, of course). Also, how would that look using metamath, since I'm in it now?

Comment: Sampling at random without replacement: ${3\choose 3}{2547 \choose 4}/{2550 \choose 7}.$ In R statistical software this is computed as `choose(2547, 4)/choose(2550,7)`, which returns `1.267973e-08`. Alternatively, look at the hypergeometric distribution and use its PDF: `dhyper(3, 3, 2547, 7)` to get the same result. [If someone wants to turn this into a formal answer, please do so.]

Comment: Thank you! Now for the second part of the question: say I don’t know how many jokers are in the deck of 2550. I draw 7 cards and get 3 jokers. What is the minimum number of jokers I can expect in that deck with 99% confidence based on that sample of 7 cards? 95% confidence?

Comment: @BruceET thank you! I took business stats in college and now 15 years later I’m working on the old text book and it’s not clicking.

Comment: Confused about your second part: If 'bimodal' means 'binomial', that must be wrong because your probabilem uses sampling without replacement. // Perhaps [this Q & A](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/425236/how-to-compute-confidence-interval-in-a-case-with-small-sample-size-small-popul/425298#425298) is relevant.

Comment: I meant binomial, and I thought that meant only 2 answers, in this case either a joker or not. I’m trying to break this problem into steps and failing. Here’s the ultimate question I’m trying to answer, based on a real world business scenario that’s causing a manager some issues (I’ve replaced scenario with more commonplace cards for familiarity):

Comment: Manager 1 took a sample of 7 cards of deck of 2550 and pulled 3 jokers. Manager 2 took the same deck of 2550 cards and sample of 19 cards and got 0 jokers. Manager 2 is being told the probability of not getting any jokers is highly improbable. I’m trying to figure out the real probability of him getting 0 jokers? 1 joker?